# Tricky Java regular expression from .. where

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression that will pick out all the words between "from" and "where" (i.e. naive table names in queries).

The following does not work, and indeed just hangs on input with no "from" at all.

```
"from(?:\\W*|(\\w*))*?where"
```

Responding to comments suggeting unconstrained backtracking, changed to

```
"from(?:\\W*+|(\\w*+))*?where"
```

No longer hangs.  But does not match "obj" (only "part") when applied to

```
select from obj, part where ...
```

Can anyone see an issue with it?  Or a better way?  Code is just

```
Matcher match = ckPattern2.matcher(query); // Hangs here.
while (match.find())
  for (int gx = 1; gx <= match.groupCount(); gx++)
    String ck = match.group(gx); ...
```

(My work around is to just to split it up into words, and then use program logic to filter.  But I hate to be beaten by a regex!)

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717832/java-pattern-matcher-freezes-when-matching-line-that-contains-n).  I believe the regex is getting stuck on the lookahead.

Comment: Based on the for-loop you wrote, I think your problem is that you are assuming that every word between "from" and "where" will be a capture group - for example "from a,b,c where". This is not the case, because the number of capture groups of a regex is fixed at compile time. If a group matches multiple pieces of the string, then only the last capture is saved.

Comment: Is there some sort of contest going on where a regex always wins?  Even if you could find a regex to do what you want (and I think you figured out you can't), a simple `split` that is easy to read beats a complicated regex that looks like your cat walked on the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

This is a parsing problem, not a scanning problem. You can't solve it with a single regular expression. You need to scan tokens, punctuation, and whitespace, and keep what you need and throw away what you don't. You will need regular expressions for tokens, punctuation, and white space. Not just a single RE.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner...

```
String[] tables = query.replaceAll("^.*?\\bfrom\\s+|\\s+where\\s+.*$", "").split("\\W+");
```

This works by first removing everything except the table names, then splits on non-word characters.

The underscore is considered a "word" character in regex, which is particularly convenient when matching "words" in the context of SQL, in which the underscore is commonly used to delimit words with an object name.